# Using R's arima function in python with rpy2

Tags: r, python-3.x

I am using rpy2 to call R functions in python3.4 and I'm struggling with calling the arima function.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

import pandas as pd

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri


ts=robjects.r('ts')
forecast=importr('forecast')

pandas2ri.activate()

traindf=pd.read_csv('MARUTI.NS.csv',index_col=0)
traindf.index=traindf.index.to_datetime()

rdata=ts(traindf.Close,frequency=1)

fit=forecast.arima(rdata,c=(1,0,0))  # error occurs here

forecast_output=forecast.forecast(fit,h=4,level=(95.0))

print(forecast_output)
```

Error:
AttributeError: 'InstalledSTPackage' object has no attribute 'arima'.

Answer (score 0):

This error meant that there was no ARIMA function in forecast. You can find it in an R environment using ?ARIMA

The forecast object is forecast.auto_arima. Alternatively, you could import stats and run the arima.

```
stats = importr("stats")
fit=stats.arima(rdata,c=(1,0,0)) \
```